# Keyframe animation not working properly on IE11

Tags: html, css

This is how it is being rendered in other browsers

[image]

This is how it is being renderd on IE11

[image]

I have used the following keyframing animation

```css
.support_team_bubble{
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 33%;
  left: 52.5%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  -webkit-animation: bubbleMoveSupport 3.5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: bubbleMoveSupport 3.5s infinite;
  -o-animation: bubbleMoveSupport 3.5s infinite; 
  animation: bubbleMoveSupport 3.5s infinite;
  -ms-animation: bubbleMoveSupport 3.5s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bubbleMoveSupport{
  0%   {left: 52.5%;}
  50%  {left: 60.2%;}
  60%  {left: 60.2%;}
  60%  {top: 33%;}
  80%  {top: 25.9%;}
  90%  {left: 60.2%;}
  90%  {top: 25.9%;}
  100% {left: 65.5%;}
  100% {top: 25.9%;}
}

@keyframes bubbleMoveSupport{
  0%   {left: 52.5%;}
  50%  {left: 60.2%;}
  60%  {left: 60.2%;}
  60%  {top: 33%;}
  80%  {top: 25.9%;}
  90%  {left: 60.2%;}
  90%  {top: 25.9%;}
  100% {left: 65.5%;}
  100% {top: 25.9%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="support_team_bubble"></div>
```

Note: the above code is for top right (first chat bubble).

Is there something I need to take care of and I am missing in case on Internet explorer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be due to the multiple declarations of percentage keyframe points. Try combining your properties for duplicate keyframe points, like so:

```css
.support_team_bubble {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 33%;
  left: 52.5%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  -webkit-animation: bubbleMoveSupport 3.5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: bubbleMoveSupport 3.5s infinite;
  -o-animation: bubbleMoveSupport 3.5s infinite;
  animation: bubbleMoveSupport 3.5s infinite;
  -ms-animation: bubbleMoveSupport 3.5s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bubbleMoveSupport{
  0%   {left: 52.5%;}
  50%  {left: 60.2%;}
  60%  {left: 60.2%; top: 33%;}
  80%  {top: 25.9%;}
  90%  {left: 60.2%; top: 25.9%;}
  100% {left: 65.5%; top: 25.9%;}
}

@keyframes bubbleMoveSupport{
  0%   {left: 52.5%;}
  50%  {left: 60.2%;}
  60%  {left: 60.2%; top: 33%;}
  80%  {top: 25.9%;}
  90%  {left: 60.2%; top: 25.9%;}
  100% {left: 65.5%; top: 25.9%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="support_team_bubble"></div>
```

Comment: If you were in front of me, I would have stanched TEDDY out of my girlfriend and would have gifted it to you <3 , thanks a ton, works like charm now!! :)